# Processing sed matching group through another sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I'd like to process the output of a compile done in linux, and convert all error references to use dos file paths which can be parsed by a windows IDE.  So, for example if I had the following line in the unix file:

```
linuxroot/a/b/c/file.c:200:1: error: evil use of / character
```

I'd like it to output:

```
d:\sftp\a\b\c\file.c:200:1: error: evil use of / character
```

So basically, I want to find anything that matches: `^\(linuxroot/[A-Za-z0-9_/.-]*\):[0-9]*:[0-9]*: error: \(.*\)$`, and then run *only* the first group through another sed replacement:
`sed -e "s|\/|\\\\|g" -e "s|^\\\\linuxroot|d:\\\\sftp"`.   Is there any mechanism in sed to do something like this?

Comment: This is a great question.  I am not very savvy using sed notation combined with complicated regex ..  But I am imagining something LIKE `sed -e "s/^\(linuxroot/[A-Za-z0-9_/.-]*\):[0-9]*:[0-9]*: error: \(.*\)$: | sed -e "s/^\\\\linuxroot|d:\\\\s
ftp':" character` which I am sure doesn't work .. But the concept that is there might spark someone more knowledgeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with this:

```
$ cat file
linuxroot/aaaaa/file.c:200:1: error: evil use of / character
linuxroot/a/bbb/file.c:200:1: error: evil use of / character
linuxroot/a/b/c/file.c:200:1: error: evil use of / character
$ cat file.sed
\!^linuxroot/[A-Za-z0-9_/.-]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*: error: .*! {
:loop
    # try to replace a '/' to the left of ':'
  s!^([^:]*)/([^:]*)!\1\\\2!
    # if succeeded, try again
  tloop
    # now there's no '/' to the left of ':'
  s!^linuxroot!d:\\sftp!
}
$ sed -E -f file.sed file
d:\sftp\aaaaa\file.c:200:1: error: evil use of / character
d:\sftp\a\bbb\file.c:200:1: error: evil use of / character
d:\sftp\a\b\c\file.c:200:1: error: evil use of / character
```

Comment: Thanks -- this works perfectly with no chance of a false hit.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;s~/([^/])(.*:)~\\\1\2~;ta;s/^linuxroot/d:\\sftp/' input_file
d:\sftp\a\b\c\file.c:200:1: error: evil use of / character
```

Comment: The second one works for me on Ubuntu 22.04.  The first one gives `sh: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected` --  Using sed (GNU sed) 4.7

Comment: @Zak I think I copied and pasted it wrong, it should be fixed now

Comment: All three versions work .. Hats off.  Saving this post  --  very useful way to use `sed`

Comment: The first two assume a path depth of four, which will unfortunately not be true for most matches.   The last one changes the / to \, which I also would not want.   I would need a generic way of changing `/`'s to `\\`s only in the first group...

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Okay. Your sample did not highlight the possible depths. Please try the edit

Answer (score 2):

Hold it, cut it, change it, grab it, mix it [[1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAjR4_CbPpQ).

```
sed '
  h                                 # hold the line in hold space
  s/:.*//                           # remove all after :
  s~/~\\~g                          # replaces slashes
  s/^linuxroot/d:\\sftp/            # replace linuxroot
  G                                 # append hold space
  s/\([^\n]*\)[^:]*\(.*\)/\1\2/     # shuffle pattern space
  '
```

> Is there any mechanism in sed to do something like this?

Yes, with hold space you can implement any kind of functionality, like a stack, where you can hold stuff for grabing later.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^linuxroot.*:/{s/:/\n&/;h;y/\//\\/;s/linuxroot/d:\\sftp/;G;s/\n.*\n//}' file
```

If a line starts with `linuxroot` and matches a `:`.

Then insert a newline before the `:`, make a copy, translate all `/` to `\`, replace `linuxroot` by `d:\sftp`, append the copy and remove the portion of the pattern space between newlines.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it's simpler with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `gensub()`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,"^linuxroot(/[[:alnum:]_/.-]*)(:[0-9]*:[0-9]*: error: .*)$",a) {
    $0 = "d:\\sftp" gensub("/","\\","g",a[1]) a[2]
} 1' file
d:\sftp\a\b\c\file.c:200:1: error: evil use of / character
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```bash
perl -pe 's|^linuxroot(/[\w/.-]+:\d+:\d+: error: )|"d:\\sftp" . $1 =~ s,/,\\,gr|e' ip.txt
```

The `e` flag allows you to use Perl code in the replacement section.

`$1 =~ s,/,\\,gr` replaces `/` with `\` only for the first capture group. `r` flag is used here to return the string instead of modifying `$1`.

`.` is string concatenation operator.